# How to Relate 2 table with each other with 2 foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my code it generates Foreign key conflict error

```
CREATE TABLE tblProducts
(
ProductID int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
ProductName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
BatchID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblBatches (BatchID)
)

CREATE TABLE tblBatches
(
BatchID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
BatchCode nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
Quantity int NOT NULL,
BatchMnf Date NOT NULL,
BatchExp Date NOT NULL,
PurchaseRate int NOT NULL,
SalesRate int NOT NULL,
ProductID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblProducts (ProductID)
)
```

Comment: You are referring to tblBatches in the first table, but it is not created yet. what is the error message you get?

Comment: here from tblProducts i want to refer BatchNumber in tblBatches and from tblBatches i want to refer ProductID in tblProducts but it gives error saying foreign key conflicts when i want to add data in any of these tables.

Comment: did you understand my comment above?

Comment: i have created tabels but error comes when i insert data in any of these tables

Comment: yes i understand what you said but i have created the tabels and both are blank yet error comes when i insert data in any of them i know error becomes because there is no data in other table to which i am refering with foriegn key.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. This is a circular reference.

This is a bad design but if you want to do that, you need to make foreign key columns Nullable.

```
CREATE TABLE tblProducts
(
ProductID int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
ProductName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
BatchID int NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblBatches (BatchID)
)

CREATE TABLE tblBatches
(
BatchID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
BatchCode nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
Quantity int NOT NULL,
BatchMnf Date NOT NULL,
BatchExp Date NOT NULL,
PurchaseRate int NOT NULL,
SalesRate int NOT NULL,
ProductID int NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblProducts (ProductID)
)
```

Then you need to update reference fields after inserting records in tblBatches and tblProducts.

---

The good design says you need to create a bridge table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblProductsBatch
(
ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
ProductID int NOT NULL,
BatchID int NOT NULL
)
```

And after inserting product and batch, you need to insert a record in this table to link rows to each other.

Comment: do you mean one table for Products one for Batches and one for bridge??

Comment: Yes this is the way to go